# Integral representation of a rational function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I would like an integral representation for the function
$$ f(x)=\frac{x(x^2-2)}{(x^2-1)^2},$$
that is I want to write it as $f(x)=\int_a^b g(x,y)dy$ for some $g(x,y)$ which is not of the form $g(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$.

It must be a definite integral, with the range of integration independent of $x$.

My first guess were beta integrals, $\int_0^1 y^a(1-y)^bdy$ with $a$ and $b$ functions of $x$, but I had no success with this.

Answer (score 2):

As an indefinite integral,

$$\int \frac{-x^{4} +3x^{2} + 2}{(x^{2} - 1)^{3}} \mathop{dx} $$

works. As a definite integral,

$$\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{x} \frac{-y^{4} + 3y^{2} + 2}{(y^{2} - 1)^{3}} \mathop{dy} $$

works.

Comment: An indefinite integral is not quite what I want, though.

Comment: Yeah and if you want definite just choose $x$ as the upper bound of integration and some root of $x(x^2-2)$ as a lower bound of integration, i.e. $0, \pm \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: yes. @TrostAft is right. i updated my post with it for you.

Comment: thanks, I gave you an upvote, but this is not what I want. I updated the question to make it clear that the range must not depend on $x$ (otherwise the problem is very easy, of course)

Answer (score 2):

Of course, there is the trivial relation

$$ \frac{\int_\alpha^\beta f(x)g(y)\text dy}{\int_\alpha^\beta g(y)\text dy} = f(x) $$

For example,

$$ \int_0^1 (k+1)y^kf(x)\text dy = f(x) $$

for any $k > -1$, or
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/2}f(x)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\text dy = f(x) $$

---

As a potentially less trivial answer, you can perform any invertible integral transform

$$ F(y) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} K(x,y)f(x)\text dx$$

Then, we can express the original function in terms of the inverse transform

$$ f(x) = \int_{y_1}^{y_2} K^{-1}(y,x)F(y)\text dy$$

As an example, using the inverse Laplace transform,

$$L_x^{-1}[f(x)](y) = \frac{1}{2}((1-2y)\sinh(y)+y\cosh(y)) $$

we can write the function

$$ f(x) = L_y[F(y)](x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2}((1-2y)\sinh(y)+y\cosh(y))\exp(-xy)\text dy $$

Comment: Not helpful at all

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. If this solution isn't valid, there should be some statement in your question that it is not.

Comment: @thedude I've updated the answer to include a less trivial solution

Comment: Yes, that is much better, thank you